# Unable to center div in another div on responsive site

Tags: html, css

I have placed a div class called `fb-page` in a number of other divs and I am trying to make it stay centred as the width of the browser changes. I can get it to stay centred up until the point where the close icon goes to the top of the page and the browser width becomes <768px - when this occurs `fb-page` goes to the left and is no longer centred.

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/1cGSRrhH)

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/LtVAMWkA)

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: may be you must look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id ="about" class="impala-prev impala-wrap-about animated impala-page">
                <div class="impala-scroll-overlay">
                        <div class="container-about">
                                <div class="block-nav">
                                        <a href="#home" class="btn-nav btn-home" data-panel="#home">
                                                <img width="20" height="20" src="img/svg/close-icon.svg" alt="close-icon">                                             
                                        </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row block-about">
                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                        <h2>About Us</h2>
                                                        <!--<h6><i>Welcome to A Vida Local (A Local Life)</i></h6>-->
                                                        <p>We are a new start-up that aims to enhance your travel experiences. A Vida Local is a community that connects those visiting Australia with the people that know it best, the locals that live there.
<br><br>
Experience Local - have a Local provide you with a unique local experience
<br>
Virtual Local - have a Local provide advice and support before your trip and while you are away.
</p>


                                                        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/avidalocal" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/avidalocal"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/avidalocal">A Vida Local</a></blockquote></div></div>


                                                </div>                         
                                        </div>         
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `align = "center"` in your div..

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/avidalocal" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-small-header="false"  data-adapt-container-width="true" align = "center" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
```